# Cypress - Windows - Getting error "npm ERR! Failed at the cypress@6.1.0 postinstall script."

Tags: cypress

I'm getting the above given error while trying to install cypress. Below given is the error. Can any one help me with this?

C:\Automation_test_LOS\Cypress>npm install cypress
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported

> cypress@6.1.0 postinstall C:\Automation_test_\Cypress\node_modules\cypress
> node index.js --exec install

Installing Cypress (version: 6.1.0)

×  Downloading Cypress
→ Cypress Version: 6.1.0
Unzipping Cypress
Finishing Installation
The Cypress App could not be downloaded.

Does your workplace require a proxy to be used to access the Internet? If so, you must configure the HTTP_PROXY environment variable before downloading Cypress. Read more: https://on.cypress.io/proxy-configuration

Otherwise, please check network connectivity and try again:

---

URL: https://download.cypress.io/desktop/6.1.0?platform=win32&arch=x64
Error: unable to get local issuer certificate

---

Platform: win32 (10.0.17134)
Cypress Version: 6.1.0
npm WARN cypress_e2e_auto@1.0.0 No repository field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! cypress@6.1.0 postinstall: `node index.js --exec install`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the cypress@6.1.0 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Test\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-12-09T12_24_40_175Z-debug.log